# how to get the all data values of a specific universal object from json output

Tags: json, python-3.x, json-normalize

- I have this currency converter api website that I have used for my converter module.
- I want to simplify the code by extracting the data from the json data shown at the bottom of the question

My Code:

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/currencies?apiKey=<API KEY>")
data = json.load(html)
currencies = data['requests']
print(currencies)
```

- The Output shows the whole JSON (as linked above) inside `{ "requests" }`
- My problem right now: How am I going to get the data values of **id** from all json objects, like a wildcard value extraction.

### JSON `data` returned by the API

```
{
    "requests": {
        "results": {
            "ALL": {
                "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
                "currencySymbol": "Lek",
                "id": "ALL"
            },
            "XCD": {
                "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "XCD"
            },
            "EUR": {
                "currencyName": "Euro",
                "currencySymbol": "€",
                "id": "EUR"
            },
            "BBD": {
                "currencyName": "Barbadian Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "BBD"
            },
            "BTN": {
                "currencyName": "Bhutanese Ngultrum",
                "id": "BTN"
            },
            "BND": {
                "currencyName": "Brunei Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "BND"
            },
            "XAF": {
                "currencyName": "Central African CFA Franc",
                "id": "XAF"
            },
            "CUP": {
                "currencyName": "Cuban Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "CUP"
            },
            "USD": {
                "currencyName": "United States Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "USD"
            },
            "FKP": {
                "currencyName": "Falkland Islands Pound",
                "currencySymbol": "£",
                "id": "FKP"
            },
            "GIP": {
                "currencyName": "Gibraltar Pound",
                "currencySymbol": "£",
                "id": "GIP"
            },
            "HUF": {
                "currencyName": "Hungarian Forint",
                "currencySymbol": "Ft",
                "id": "HUF"
            },
            "IRR": {
                "currencyName": "Iranian Rial",
                "currencySymbol": "﷼",
                "id": "IRR"
            },
            "JMD": {
                "currencyName": "Jamaican Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "J$",
                "id": "JMD"
            },
            "AUD": {
                "currencyName": "Australian Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "AUD"
            },
            "LAK": {
                "currencyName": "Lao Kip",
                "currencySymbol": "₭",
                "id": "LAK"
            },
            "LYD": {
                "currencyName": "Libyan Dinar",
                "id": "LYD"
            },
            "MKD": {
                "currencyName": "Macedonian Denar",
                "currencySymbol": "ден",
                "id": "MKD"
            },
            "XOF": {
                "currencyName": "West African CFA Franc",
                "id": "XOF"
            },
            "NZD": {
                "currencyName": "New Zealand Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "NZD"
            },
            "OMR": {
                "currencyName": "Omani Rial",
                "currencySymbol": "﷼",
                "id": "OMR"
            },
            "PGK": {
                "currencyName": "Papua New Guinean Kina",
                "id": "PGK"
            },
            "RWF": {
                "currencyName": "Rwandan Franc",
                "id": "RWF"
            },
            "WST": {
                "currencyName": "Samoan Tala",
                "id": "WST"
            },
            "RSD": {
                "currencyName": "Serbian Dinar",
                "currencySymbol": "Дин.",
                "id": "RSD"
            },
            "SEK": {
                "currencyName": "Swedish Krona",
                "currencySymbol": "kr",
                "id": "SEK"
            },
            "TZS": {
                "currencyName": "Tanzanian Shilling",
                "currencySymbol": "TSh",
                "id": "TZS"
            },
            "AMD": {
                "currencyName": "Armenian Dram",
                "id": "AMD"
            },
            "BSD": {
                "currencyName": "Bahamian Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "BSD"
            },
            "BAM": {
                "currencyName": "Bosnia And Herzegovina Konvertibilna Marka",
                "currencySymbol": "KM",
                "id": "BAM"
            },
            "CVE": {
                "currencyName": "Cape Verdean Escudo",
                "id": "CVE"
            },
            "CNY": {
                "currencyName": "Chinese Yuan",
                "currencySymbol": "¥",
                "id": "CNY"
            },
            "CRC": {
                "currencyName": "Costa Rican Colon",
                "currencySymbol": "₡",
                "id": "CRC"
            },
            "CZK": {
                "currencyName": "Czech Koruna",
                "currencySymbol": "Kč",
                "id": "CZK"
            },
            "ERN": {
                "currencyName": "Eritrean Nakfa",
                "id": "ERN"
            },
            "GEL": {
                "currencyName": "Georgian Lari",
                "id": "GEL"
            },
            "HTG": {
                "currencyName": "Haitian Gourde",
                "id": "HTG"
            },
            "INR": {
                "currencyName": "Indian Rupee",
                "currencySymbol": "₹",
                "id": "INR"
            },
            "JOD": {
                "currencyName": "Jordanian Dinar",
                "id": "JOD"
            },
            "KRW": {
                "currencyName": "South Korean Won",
                "currencySymbol": "₩",
                "id": "KRW"
            },
            "LBP": {
                "currencyName": "Lebanese Lira",
                "currencySymbol": "£",
                "id": "LBP"
            },
            "MWK": {
                "currencyName": "Malawian Kwacha",
                "id": "MWK"
            },
            "MRO": {
                "currencyName": "Mauritanian Ouguiya",
                "id": "MRO"
            },
            "MZN": {
                "currencyName": "Mozambican Metical",
                "id": "MZN"
            },
            "ANG": {
                "currencyName": "Netherlands Antillean Gulden",
                "currencySymbol": "ƒ",
                "id": "ANG"
            },
            "PEN": {
                "currencyName": "Peruvian Nuevo Sol",
                "currencySymbol": "S/.",
                "id": "PEN"
            },
            "QAR": {
                "currencyName": "Qatari Riyal",
                "currencySymbol": "﷼",
                "id": "QAR"
            },
            "STD": {
                "currencyName": "Sao Tome And Principe Dobra",
                "id": "STD"
            },
            "SLL": {
                "currencyName": "Sierra Leonean Leone",
                "id": "SLL"
            },
            "SOS": {
                "currencyName": "Somali Shilling",
                "currencySymbol": "S",
                "id": "SOS"
            },
            "SDG": {
                "currencyName": "Sudanese Pound",
                "id": "SDG"
            },
            "SYP": {
                "currencyName": "Syrian Pound",
                "currencySymbol": "£",
                "id": "SYP"
            },
            "AOA": {
                "currencyName": "Angolan Kwanza",
                "id": "AOA"
            },
            "AWG": {
                "currencyName": "Aruban Florin",
                "currencySymbol": "ƒ",
                "id": "AWG"
            },
            "BHD": {
                "currencyName": "Bahraini Dinar",
                "id": "BHD"
            },
            "BZD": {
                "currencyName": "Belize Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "BZ$",
                "id": "BZD"
            },
            "BWP": {
                "currencyName": "Botswana Pula",
                "currencySymbol": "P",
                "id": "BWP"
            },
            "BIF": {
                "currencyName": "Burundi Franc",
                "id": "BIF"
            },
            "KYD": {
                "currencyName": "Cayman Islands Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "KYD"
            },
            "COP": {
                "currencyName": "Colombian Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "COP"
            },
            "DKK": {
                "currencyName": "Danish Krone",
                "currencySymbol": "kr",
                "id": "DKK"
            },
            "GTQ": {
                "currencyName": "Guatemalan Quetzal",
                "currencySymbol": "Q",
                "id": "GTQ"
            },
            "HNL": {
                "currencyName": "Honduran Lempira",
                "currencySymbol": "L",
                "id": "HNL"
            },
            "IDR": {
                "currencyName": "Indonesian Rupiah",
                "currencySymbol": "Rp",
                "id": "IDR"
            },
            "ILS": {
                "currencyName": "Israeli New Sheqel",
                "currencySymbol": "₪",
                "id": "ILS"
            },
            "KZT": {
                "currencyName": "Kazakhstani Tenge",
                "currencySymbol": "лв",
                "id": "KZT"
            },
            "KWD": {
                "currencyName": "Kuwaiti Dinar",
                "id": "KWD"
            },
            "LSL": {
                "currencyName": "Lesotho Loti",
                "id": "LSL"
            },
            "MYR": {
                "currencyName": "Malaysian Ringgit",
                "currencySymbol": "RM",
                "id": "MYR"
            },
            "MUR": {
                "currencyName": "Mauritian Rupee",
                "currencySymbol": "₨",
                "id": "MUR"
            },
            "MNT": {
                "currencyName": "Mongolian Tugrik",
                "currencySymbol": "₮",
                "id": "MNT"
            },
            "MMK": {
                "currencyName": "Myanma Kyat",
                "id": "MMK"
            },
            "NGN": {
                "currencyName": "Nigerian Naira",
                "currencySymbol": "₦",
                "id": "NGN"
            },
            "PAB": {
                "currencyName": "Panamanian Balboa",
                "currencySymbol": "B/.",
                "id": "PAB"
            },
            "PHP": {
                "currencyName": "Philippine Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "₱",
                "id": "PHP"
            },
            "RON": {
                "currencyName": "Romanian Leu",
                "currencySymbol": "lei",
                "id": "RON"
            },
            "SAR": {
                "currencyName": "Saudi Riyal",
                "currencySymbol": "﷼",
                "id": "SAR"
            },
            "SGD": {
                "currencyName": "Singapore Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "SGD"
            },
            "ZAR": {
                "currencyName": "South African Rand",
                "currencySymbol": "R",
                "id": "ZAR"
            },
            "SRD": {
                "currencyName": "Surinamese Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "SRD"
            },
            "TWD": {
                "currencyName": "New Taiwan Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "NT$",
                "id": "TWD"
            },
            "TOP": {
                "currencyName": "Paanga",
                "id": "TOP"
            },
            "VEF": {
                "currencyName": "Venezuelan Bolivar",
                "id": "VEF"
            },
            "DZD": {
                "currencyName": "Algerian Dinar",
                "id": "DZD"
            },
            "ARS": {
                "currencyName": "Argentine Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "ARS"
            },
            "AZN": {
                "currencyName": "Azerbaijani Manat",
                "currencySymbol": "ман",
                "id": "AZN"
            },
            "BYR": {
                "currencyName": "Belarusian Ruble",
                "currencySymbol": "p.",
                "id": "BYR"
            },
            "BOB": {
                "currencyName": "Bolivian Boliviano",
                "currencySymbol": "$b",
                "id": "BOB"
            },
            "BGN": {
                "currencyName": "Bulgarian Lev",
                "currencySymbol": "лв",
                "id": "BGN"
            },
            "CAD": {
                "currencyName": "Canadian Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "CAD"
            },
            "CLP": {
                "currencyName": "Chilean Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "CLP"
            },
            "CDF": {
                "currencyName": "Congolese Franc",
                "id": "CDF"
            },
            "DOP": {
                "currencyName": "Dominican Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "RD$",
                "id": "DOP"
            },
            "FJD": {
                "currencyName": "Fijian Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "FJD"
            },
            "GMD": {
                "currencyName": "Gambian Dalasi",
                "id": "GMD"
            },
            "GYD": {
                "currencyName": "Guyanese Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "GYD"
            },
            "ISK": {
                "currencyName": "Icelandic Króna",
                "currencySymbol": "kr",
                "id": "ISK"
            },
            "IQD": {
                "currencyName": "Iraqi Dinar",
                "id": "IQD"
            },
            "JPY": {
                "currencyName": "Japanese Yen",
                "currencySymbol": "¥",
                "id": "JPY"
            },
            "KPW": {
                "currencyName": "North Korean Won",
                "currencySymbol": "₩",
                "id": "KPW"
            },
            "LVL": {
                "currencyName": "Latvian Lats",
                "currencySymbol": "Ls",
                "id": "LVL"
            },
            "CHF": {
                "currencyName": "Swiss Franc",
                "currencySymbol": "Fr.",
                "id": "CHF"
            },
            "MGA": {
                "currencyName": "Malagasy Ariary",
                "id": "MGA"
            },
            "MDL": {
                "currencyName": "Moldovan Leu",
                "id": "MDL"
            },
            "MAD": {
                "currencyName": "Moroccan Dirham",
                "id": "MAD"
            },
            "NPR": {
                "currencyName": "Nepalese Rupee",
                "currencySymbol": "₨",
                "id": "NPR"
            },
            "NIO": {
                "currencyName": "Nicaraguan Cordoba",
                "currencySymbol": "C$",
                "id": "NIO"
            },
            "PKR": {
                "currencyName": "Pakistani Rupee",
                "currencySymbol": "₨",
                "id": "PKR"
            },
            "PYG": {
                "currencyName": "Paraguayan Guarani",
                "currencySymbol": "Gs",
                "id": "PYG"
            },
            "SHP": {
                "currencyName": "Saint Helena Pound",
                "currencySymbol": "£",
                "id": "SHP"
            },
            "SCR": {
                "currencyName": "Seychellois Rupee",
                "currencySymbol": "₨",
                "id": "SCR"
            },
            "SBD": {
                "currencyName": "Solomon Islands Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "SBD"
            },
            "LKR": {
                "currencyName": "Sri Lankan Rupee",
                "currencySymbol": "₨",
                "id": "LKR"
            },
            "THB": {
                "currencyName": "Thai Baht",
                "currencySymbol": "฿",
                "id": "THB"
            },
            "TRY": {
                "currencyName": "Turkish New Lira",
                "id": "TRY"
            },
            "AED": {
                "currencyName": "UAE Dirham",
                "id": "AED"
            },
            "VUV": {
                "currencyName": "Vanuatu Vatu",
                "id": "VUV"
            },
            "YER": {
                "currencyName": "Yemeni Rial",
                "currencySymbol": "﷼",
                "id": "YER"
            },
            "AFN": {
                "currencyName": "Afghan Afghani",
                "currencySymbol": "؋",
                "id": "AFN"
            },
            "BDT": {
                "currencyName": "Bangladeshi Taka",
                "id": "BDT"
            },
            "BRL": {
                "currencyName": "Brazilian Real",
                "currencySymbol": "R$",
                "id": "BRL"
            },
            "KHR": {
                "currencyName": "Cambodian Riel",
                "currencySymbol": "៛",
                "id": "KHR"
            },
            "KMF": {
                "currencyName": "Comorian Franc",
                "id": "KMF"
            },
            "HRK": {
                "currencyName": "Croatian Kuna",
                "currencySymbol": "kn",
                "id": "HRK"
            },
            "DJF": {
                "currencyName": "Djiboutian Franc",
                "id": "DJF"
            },
            "EGP": {
                "currencyName": "Egyptian Pound",
                "currencySymbol": "£",
                "id": "EGP"
            },
            "ETB": {
                "currencyName": "Ethiopian Birr",
                "id": "ETB"
            },
            "XPF": {
                "currencyName": "CFP Franc",
                "id": "XPF"
            },
            "GHS": {
                "currencyName": "Ghanaian Cedi",
                "id": "GHS"
            },
            "GNF": {
                "currencyName": "Guinean Franc",
                "id": "GNF"
            },
            "HKD": {
                "currencyName": "Hong Kong Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "HKD"
            },
            "XDR": {
                "currencyName": "Special Drawing Rights",
                "id": "XDR"
            },
            "KES": {
                "currencyName": "Kenyan Shilling",
                "currencySymbol": "KSh",
                "id": "KES"
            },
            "KGS": {
                "currencyName": "Kyrgyzstani Som",
                "currencySymbol": "лв",
                "id": "KGS"
            },
            "LRD": {
                "currencyName": "Liberian Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "LRD"
            },
            "MOP": {
                "currencyName": "Macanese Pataca",
                "id": "MOP"
            },
            "MVR": {
                "currencyName": "Maldivian Rufiyaa",
                "id": "MVR"
            },
            "MXN": {
                "currencyName": "Mexican Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "MXN"
            },
            "NAD": {
                "currencyName": "Namibian Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "$",
                "id": "NAD"
            },
            "NOK": {
                "currencyName": "Norwegian Krone",
                "currencySymbol": "kr",
                "id": "NOK"
            },
            "PLN": {
                "currencyName": "Polish Zloty",
                "currencySymbol": "zł",
                "id": "PLN"
            },
            "RUB": {
                "currencyName": "Russian Ruble",
                "currencySymbol": "руб",
                "id": "RUB"
            },
            "SZL": {
                "currencyName": "Swazi Lilangeni",
                "id": "SZL"
            },
            "TJS": {
                "currencyName": "Tajikistani Somoni",
                "id": "TJS"
            },
            "TTD": {
                "currencyName": "Trinidad and Tobago Dollar",
                "currencySymbol": "TT$",
                "id": "TTD"
            },
            "UGX": {
                "currencyName": "Ugandan Shilling",
                "currencySymbol": "USh",
                "id": "UGX"
            },
            "UYU": {
                "currencyName": "Uruguayan Peso",
                "currencySymbol": "$U",
                "id": "UYU"
            },
            "VND": {
                "currencyName": "Vietnamese Dong",
                "currencySymbol": "₫",
                "id": "VND"
            },
            "TND": {
                "currencyName": "Tunisian Dinar",
                "id": "TND"
            },
            "UAH": {
                "currencyName": "Ukrainian Hryvnia",
                "currencySymbol": "₴",
                "id": "UAH"
            },
            "UZS": {
                "currencyName": "Uzbekistani Som",
                "currencySymbol": "лв",
                "id": "UZS"
            },
            "TMT": {
                "currencyName": "Turkmenistan Manat",
                "id": "TMT"
            },
            "GBP": {
                "currencyName": "British Pound",
                "currencySymbol": "£",
                "id": "GBP"
            },
            "ZMW": {
                "currencyName": "Zambian Kwacha",
                "id": "ZMW"
            },
            "BTC": {
                "currencyName": "Bitcoin",
                "currencySymbol": "BTC",
                "id": "BTC"
            },
            "BYN": {
                "currencyName": "New Belarusian Ruble",
                "currencySymbol": "p.",
                "id": "BYN"
            },
            "BMD": {
                "currencyName": "Bermudan Dollar",
                "id": "BMD"
            },
            "GGP": {
                "currencyName": "Guernsey Pound",
                "id": "GGP"
            },
            "CLF": {
                "currencyName": "Chilean Unit Of Account",
                "id": "CLF"
            },
            "CUC": {
                "currencyName": "Cuban Convertible Peso",
                "id": "CUC"
            },
            "IMP": {
                "currencyName": "Manx pound",
                "id": "IMP"
            },
            "JEP": {
                "currencyName": "Jersey Pound",
                "id": "JEP"
            },
            "SVC": {
                "currencyName": "Salvadoran Colón",
                "id": "SVC"
            },
            "ZMK": {
                "currencyName": "Old Zambian Kwacha",
                "id": "ZMK"
            },
            "XAG": {
                "currencyName": "Silver (troy ounce)",
                "id": "XAG"
            },
            "ZWL": {
                "currencyName": "Zimbabwean Dollar",
                "id": "ZWL"
            }
        },
        "note": "Please don't use this sample API key in your environment. Doing so will get you banned. You may get your free API key at free.currencyconverterapi.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Given your `data` object

- The `key-value` pair with `id` is under `data['results']`

  - Iterate through each `key` (e.g. `'BTN'`) and `value` (`{'currencyName': 'Bhutanese Ngultrum', 'id': 'BTN'}`) to get the `id`
- The `key` for each currency is also the `id`

  - `'BTN': {'currencyName': 'Bhutanese Ngultrum', 'id': 'BTN'}`

### Use pandas

- This will give you all the data, not just `id`
- Use [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) & [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to create a dataframe of the JSON data.

  - `pd.json_normalize(v) for v in data['results'].values()` creates a dataframe for each `{'currencyName': 'Albanian Lek', 'currencySymbol': 'Lek', 'id': 'ALL'}`
  - `pd.concat(...)` combines all the dataframes into one dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

# load all the currencies into the dataframe
df = pd.concat(pd.json_normalize(v) for v in data['results'].values()).reset_index(drop=True)

# display df
            currencyName currencySymbol   id
0           Albanian Lek            Lek  ALL
1  East Caribbean Dollar              $  XCD
2                   Euro              €  EUR
3       Barbadian Dollar              $  BBD
4     Bhutanese Ngultrum            NaN  BTN

# save all the data to csv
df.to_csv('currencies.csv', index=False)

# get a list of id
ids = df.id.tolist()
```

### Without pandas

- If you just want all the `id` values
- The following code will produce a list with all the `id` values.

```py
ids = list()
for v in data['results'].values():
    ids.append(v['id'])


# as a list-comprehension 
ids = [v['id'] for v in data['results'].values()]
```